# Unable to setGID bit on folder

Tags: permissions, directory, shared-folders

I want that all files and directories inherit the permissions of the tvshow folder.

I am trying to set the GID bit, but I have no idea why it's not working. I am using this [source](http://www.library.yale.edu/wsg/docs/permissions/sgid.htm) for my commands.

```
david@server:~/media$ ls -l
drwxrwx--- 11 root media_users 11 Jul 23 18:58 tvshows

david@server:~/media$ sudo chmod 2770 tvshows/

david@server:~/media$ ls -l
drwxrwx--- 11 root media_users 11 Jul 23 18:58 tvshows
```

The permissions have not changed after executing the command.

I have also tried using `chmod g+s`

EDIT:

```
david@server:~/media$ sudo -g media_users chmod 2770 tvshows/
chmod: changing permissions of ‘tvshows/’: Operation not permitted
```

Mount options:

```
david@server:~/media$ sudo zfs get mountpoint storagedata
NAME         PROPERTY    VALUE             SOURCE
storagedata  mountpoint  /mnt/storagedata  local

david@server:/proc$ cat mounts
storagedata /mnt/storagedata zfs rw,relatime,xattr,noacl 0 0
```

Comment: Is `media` a local directory, or a separately mounted filesystem? if the latter, what are its mount options - in particular, is the `nosuid` option in effect?

Comment: @steeldriver Great idea! The folder is part of a ZFS storage pool. I have added the mount options to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable ACL in my zfs pool

```
sudo zfs set aclinherit=passthrough storagedata
```

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-2271/gbaaz/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

From `man chmod`:

```
SETUID AND SETGID BITS
       chmod clears the set-group-ID bit of a regular file if the file's group
       ID  does  not  match the user's effective group ID or one of the user's
       supplementary group IDs, unless the user  has  appropriate  privileges.
       Additional restrictions may cause the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits
       of MODE or RFILE to be ignored.
```

In my interpretation, that means that `media_users` is not the effective group for the root user that issues the command. To execute the command with media_users as the effective group, try: `sudo -g media_users chmod 2770 tvshows/`.

Comment: Apparently I do not have the permission to do that, even as sudo

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the `umask` to `0002` :

```
umask 0002
```